# Skipping some content of XML while parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

Hi I have a XMl response string which contains a lot of useless elements, but as we know the NSXMLParser is designed n such a way that it visits every element, This process is really killing my speed . Is there any way by which I can skip some of the elements. Below is my XML string, I want to skip the **xs:schema** element.

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.sample.com/researchportal/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="state" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="userid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<state>True</state>
<userid>16</userid>
<message/>
</Table1>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: show ur code.... you can just skip that keyword.

Comment: thanks for fast response I want to skip the whole xs:schema block in one check, I dont want to check each elemnt inside xs:schema

Comment: add your code which you are using for parsing.

Comment: I am using the regular way of parsing the xml, using 3 delegates of NSXMLParserDelegate, and comparing the strings needeed in each method. But as the elemnts inside the xs:schema element areuseless to me , I want to skip those iterations.

Comment: Please add your code in your question by editing it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make `NSXMLParser` skip elements. You can ignore them in the delegate methods, but the parser will visit all nodes.

Comment: @MartinR: yeah thats what I also think , but assuming that there may be any of the brother in this great community who might know a little bit more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out a way may be its not the best one but some how I am getting a fast parsing.

```
NSData * fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
xmlParser  = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[self removeElements:fileData]];
[xmlParser setDelegate:objUtil];
success = [xmlParser parse];
```

I ahve ceated a method `removeElements:fileData`, which accepts NSData and returns the same, with the required result(bY trimming the xml string).

```
- (NSData*) removeElements :(NSData*)data
{
NSMutableString * strFromData = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange startRange = [strFromData rangeOfString:@"<xs:schema"];
NSRange endRange = [strFromData rangeOfString:@"<diffgr"];
[strFromData replaceCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(startRange.location,endRange.location - startRange.location) withString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@",strFromData);
NSData *retData = [strFromData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return retData;
}
```

Thanks to all the friends who took out time of their busy works to help me  :)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution you are looking for, but however i am going to write it if it can help you

You can declare the string as constants like

```
static NSString *kItem1 = @"ItemToMatch";
```

In didStart and didEnd functions the comparison can be done with constants, like :

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:kItem1]) {}
```

It will reduce the number of objects created during parsing, hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks for answer but it still is doing comparison and will do for all the elements, hence the same case..

Comment: yes i know i am still searching regarding this, but the answer i gave was just to make comparisons fast i thought may be it could enhance the performance remarkably

Comment: Try using [self parser:(NSXMLParser *)self didEndElement:elementName namespaceURI:namespaceURI qualifiedName:qName]; when you encounter @"xs:schema" during parsing

Comment: Will this not enter the element and traverse other elemnts inside it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) parsing Library for iOS.This is a DOM Parser easy to use.

You can find parser comparison here : [Ray Wenderlich Blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Comment: will it solve the problem mentioned here.. dont give irrelevant answers.

Comment: @vishwa.deepak : I think your comment is quite rude. First you ask question to seek solution to your problem and Instead of checking out what he suggested you are turning him down.

Comment: @rohan-patel: its not about being rude .. giving irrelevant answers just prohibits the chances of getting required solution, people oversee the question when they see its answered, and its left unanswered as always. By the Alak is not my enemy. :)

Comment: If he is wrong then he will get down vote and with -ve votes people won't get prohibited getting proper solution, IMO.

Comment: You could have said the same thing in a bit more milder tone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26017/discussion-between-vishwa-deepak-and-rohan-patel)